# BQ Table metadata - access via StandardSQL

Tags: google-bigquery

Id like to be able to access BQ table metadata via standardSQL - namely last modified time (to build an alert system where we expect updates (inserts) in a certain period of time)

Its possible with legacySQL, but cant see anything on standardSQL?  Or did I miss it?  Assume such a query is 0 cost.

Is there a better way to do this with stackdriver monitoring (the alerts that is?).

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is free

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT table_id,
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time)) AS creation_date,
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time)) AS last_modified_date,
  row_count,
  size_bytes,
  CASE
    WHEN type = 1 THEN 'table'
    WHEN type = 2 THEN 'view'
    WHEN type = 3 THEN 'external'
    ELSE '?'
  END AS type,
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time,
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time,
  dataset_id,
  project_id
FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.__TABLES__`
```